# ¿Cómo ordenar por las 25 filas más recientes y las 25 más antiguas?

Tags: sql, servidor

Hola que tal quisiera saber como en una sola consulta traer 25 registros mas recientes y 25 antiguos tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 25 * FROM ubicaciones ORDER BY fecha) RECIENTE
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 25  * FROM ubicaciones ORDER BY fecha DESC) ANTIGUOS
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

quiero que salga por fecha y hora pero no se si la conulta esta bien me funciona pero no se si en mejor practica esta bien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra forma bastante práctica y sencilla es generar un número de fila dependiendo el orden y filtrar por aquellas menores o iguales a 25

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (SELECT    *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS OA,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fecha ASC)  AS OD
        FROM ubicaciones
    ) T
    WHERE T.OA <= 25 OR T.OD <= 25
    ORDER BY T.OA ASC, T.OD DESC
```

Comment: graciaaaaas me fue mas funcional esta query de hecho amigo si quiesiera ordenar por fecha y hora como seria gracias

Comment: Deberías simplemente modificar el orden de los los `ROW_NUMBER()` algo así `OVER (ORDER BY fecha DESC, Hora DESC)` y el otro igual pero con orden `ASC`

Comment: gracias ultima pregunta en los ultimos registros que son de mas antiguos la hora me la presenta 13:15:15, 13:15:13 y si la quiero que tambien me la ponga mas antiigua asi 13:15:13
13:15:15

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta está bien, pero para lograr lo final, deberías embeberla en un **SELECT** y hacerle un **ORDER BY**. A continuación te paso la consulta con unos ligeros cambios:

```
SELECT*
FROM (
    SELECT 'RECIENTE' AS 'Consulta', * -- le agrego un campo para distinguir de que consulta viene
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 25* 
        FROM ubicaciones 
        ORDER BY fecha
    ) AS X

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'ANTIGUOS' AS 'Consulta', * -- le agrego un campo para distinguir de que consulta viene
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 25* 
        FROM ubicaciones 
        ORDER BY fecha DESC
    ) AS Y
) AS Z
ORDER BY Z.fecha DESC  -- Se ordena en base al campo fecha.
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: si me funciona amigo que pasaria si quieroque ordene por hora tambien puedo poner algo asi order by fecha, hora y ORDER BY fecha, hora DESC

Comment: Claro, si te fijas en la parte final de la sentencia, ya el tema de ordenamiento queda a tu criterio. Saludos.

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGO ME FUNCIONO DE HECHO GRACIAS

Comment: No hay de que. Suerte y éxitos!.